# Custom media features

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries

I have a webpage that I want to be able to display in two different ways. The elements on this page have two sets of styles, one for each way of displaying. I want to be able to easily switch the styling of all elements from one set of styles to another at will in javascript.

I would also like to have it so only the second set of styles can be used if the screen width is below some threshold.

I'm wondering if there's anyway to set custom media features, so I can define my styles like this:

```
@media (custom-feature: 'first-set') and (min-width: 700px) {
  /* first set of styles goes here */
}
@media(custom-feature: 'second-set'), (max-width : 700px) {
  /* second set of styles goes here */
}
```

and then do something like this in my javascript:

```
setMediaFeature('custom-feature', 'second-set')
```

It looks like this might be a part of Media Queries 4, but I'm wondering if there's any way to achieve the same effect right now.

Comment: You could achieve a similar function by adding a classname to the body element. Then in the CSS you could create a styles using `.first-set {}` and `.second-set {}`

Comment: I think that would require me to include the second set of styles in two places, once in `.second-set {}` and once in `@media(max-width : 700px){}`

Comment: late comment  , but something seems to come up https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/WD-mediaqueries-4-20160126/#custom-mq